# Javascript nested loops

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Hello I am new to javascript can someone tell me how since I have defined all of the months how would I display the odd numbers or the even number of months?

Thank you.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Show Odd Months</title>
    <script>
      function demo(){
    var month = new Array(5);
     month[1] = "January";
     month[2] = "February";
     month[3] = "March";
     month[4] = "April";
     month[5] = "May";      
     month[6] = "June"; 
     month[7] = "July"; 
     month[8] = "August"; 
     month[9] = "September";
     month[10] = "October";
     month[11] = "November";   
     month[12] = "December";
        
        
      for (var i in month)
      {
        document.write("month[" + i + "]  = " + month[i] + "<br/>");        
      }
      
      }
      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button below</p>
  <button onclick="demo()">Show Odd Months</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i += 2)`? If you start at 0 you get evens, if you start at 1 you get odds. (Or you would if you filled your array starting at index 0 like normal)

Comment: Also, why did you put a 5 here? `var month = new Array(5);` You obviously don't want an array with 5 things, you want it with 12.

Comment: that's basic math of finding odd and even numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with step of 2, and start with 1 for even, and 0 for odd (since arrays are 0 based, and months are 1 based). Since the idea for odd and even is similar, we can create one function that produces the relevant (odd, even) functions by changing a couple of parameters.

```js
// the array is created using an array literal
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

// showMonths takes a start and end values, and returns a functions that uses those values when invoked
function showMonths(start, step) {
  start = start || 0; // if start is not stated, it's 0
  step = step || 1; // if step is not stated or is 0, it's 1

  return function() {
    // the loop uses start and step to iterate
    for (var i = start; i < months.length; i += step) {
      document.write("month[" + i + "]  = " + months[i] + "<br/>");
    }
  }
}


var showOdd = showMonths(0, 2); // create showOdd by using start 0, and step 2
var showEven = showMonths(1, 2); // create showEven by using start 1, and step 2
```

```html
<button onclick="showOdd()">Show Odd Months</button>
<button onclick="showEven()">Show Even Months</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus division to tell if the index is odd. Modulus division is like normal division, except the answer is the remainder. The operator here is `%`.

```
for (var i in month)
{
    if (i % 2 === 1) {
        document.write("month[" + i + "]  = " + month[i] + "<br/>");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if i is odd or even.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Show Odd Months</title>
    <script>
      function demo(){
    var month = new Array(5);
     month[1] = "January";
     month[2] = "February";
     month[3] = "March";
     month[4] = "April";
     month[5] = "May";      
     month[6] = "June"; 
     month[7] = "July"; 
     month[8] = "August"; 
     month[9] = "September";
     month[10] = "October";
     month[11] = "November";   
     month[12] = "December";
        
        
      for (var i in month)
      {if (i%2 ==0){
        document.write("month[" + i + "]  = " + month[i] + "<br/>");        
      }
}
      
      }
      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button below</p>
  <button onclick="demo()">Show Odd Months</button>

</body>
</html>
```